# App crashes after receiving SMS with Flutter "sms 0.2.4" library

Tags: flutter, sms

I am using Flutter's `sms: 0.2.4` library for sending and receiving sms and I have created a sample page according to its Git Repository.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

void sendMsg(){

  SmsSender sender = new SmsSender();
  String address = '09199375728';
  SmsMessage message = new SmsMessage(address, 'سلام!!!');
  message.onStateChanged.listen((state) {
  if (state == SmsMessageState.Sent) {
  print("SMS is sent!");
  } else if (state == SmsMessageState.Delivered) {
  print("SMS is delivered!");
  }
  });
  sender.sendSms(message);
}

void receiveMsg() {
  SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();
  receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) => print(msg.body));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(onPressed: sendMsg, child: Text('send sms')),
            Divider(),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: receiveMsg, child: Text('start receiving sms')),

          ],)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Sending message has no problem but when I call receiveMsg() method and a sms receives it crashes with this error:

```
I have a problem using your Flutter sms library: when I receive sms app crashes with this error:
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725): Process: com.example.flutterapp, PID: 8725
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.flutterapp.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.flutterapp.AlarmReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.flutterapp-fvYNOtacV-27aTk0nXKMMA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.flutterapp-fvYNOtacV-27aTk0nXKMMA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.flutterapp-fvYNOtacV-27aTk0nXKMMA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3198)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.flutterapp.AlarmReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.flutterapp-fvYNOtacV-27aTk0nXKMMA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.flutterapp-fvYNOtacV-27aTk0nXKMMA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.flutterapp-fvYNOtacV-27aTk0nXKMMA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3193)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8725):    ... 8 more
```

I checked android manifest file for permission of send and receive sms and it was ok but I don't know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.flutterapp.AlarmReceiver:

means it's unable to find the class file, look at the dex files generated and see if the class file has been renamed to something else or is in a different package